# "The parameter CNAME contains one or more parameters that are not valid" error message while deploying a CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, provisioning

I'm getting this error message when trying to deploy a CloudFront distribution:

```
The parameter CNAME contains one or more parameters that are not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: dfeb983d-b398-11e8-a2d5-5f6a8378e402)
```

I'm following the guide at http://templates.cloudonaut.io/en/stable/wordpress/#wordpress-fault-tolerant-and-scalable-mysql.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the resource in your template responsible for creating the Cloudfront distribution?  Also which region are you provisioning to?

Comment: I am provisioning to us-east-1 for all resources including my SSL Certificates.


Here is the resources:
https://pastebin.com/i7j9atgh

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else running into this issue, I ran into this issue today, and it turned out I had a misunderstanding about the HostedZone parameter in AWS's sample CloudFormation template - I had provided the Hosted Zone ID when the parameter was expecting the actual domain of the Hosted Zone. In this question's sample template, for example, the value of '${SubDomainNameWithDot}${HostedZoneName}' would need to be a valid domain name.

Answer (score 3):

for me the CNAME just hava an extra blank space.
delete the blank space and everthing is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have a blank entry in the `Alternate domain name (CNAME) - optional` section.

In other words, do not click `Add Item` and leave it blank.  If you do and click save, it will think the blank entry is an alternate domain and give you the error: `The parameter CNAME contains one or more parameters that are too small.`

Comment: most useful answer for me!

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this issue by attempting to manually create the CloudFront distribution in the AWS console. When I pasted in the CNAME into *"Settings / Alternate domain name (CNAME) - optional"*, it showed me the following warning:

> Alternative domain name must contain one or more dots (.) and can only include lower case alphanumeric characters, dashes (-), and, optionally, a leading "*." to indicate all subdomains of the specified domain, for example, "*.example.com".

After I conformed my domain name to those requirements (i.e., converting to lowercase), **the distribution deployed cleanly.**

---

`The parameter CNAME contains one or more parameters that are not valid` is not a very helpful message — that should be improved!

Comment: I'm using the cdk and my issue was I used a stage that had an uppercase character in it and cloudfront was rejecting my domain name